# Merge connected UIBezierPaths

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath

Is there some way (code or pseudo-code algorithm) to utilize `UIBezierPath` instance methods like `appendPath` to "merge" any number of connected, distinct `UIBezierPath`s into a single big path? In a document with many paths, I am trying to reduce the encoded file size by perhaps reducing the number of paths as there is surely some redundant information there. If I am barking up the wrong tree, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if its only an esthetically problem...just set the first point of the 2nd bezier curve as the last point of the 1st..and so on..

if its not i don't think there is a way to merge 2 or more bezier paths cuz ...well..they are bezier and it wont look right if you do

read more about bezier curves
[bezier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) and see why it wont work

Comment: The problem is that the first point of the 2nd curve may not be connected to the last point of the 1st, so it would not reflect the drawer's intention

Comment: then what's the point of the question? i mean...if its not connected there are 2 diferent bezier curves..and if it is..use my solution...simple as that. There's no other way that you can do what you want to do using bezier curves..i may be wrong tho

Comment: You're right, I was thinking that it might have some member array of sub paths but that is not the case. Dumb question.

Comment: Not a dumb question. Not merging is not just an aesthetics issue. Certain behaviors, such as clipping and filling, differ if the paths are connected vs. if they are simply an assemblage of paths. Note that Apple's documentation states that no attempt is made to line up the points, but that there could be behavior as if they did. I'm currently working on a project where it would be easiest if I could merge the lines for clipping reasons because I'm doing different transforms to each segment. They are guaranteed to align endpoint to endpoint.

Comment: i just recently gone into image processing and UIBezierPath has "appendPath:" method, which does exactly that . Also this question was from an year ago :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had few logically connected paths that together form a closed shape and I wanted to fill this closed shape. This cannot be done if you just [append(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624377-append) them together as the fill would simply applied to each path. I looked at similar questions asked but none of them solved the problem. So I wrote this extension to merge logically connected paths together to form a single path.

If you have `path1`, `path2` and `path3` logically form a closed shape. Call them in the same order

```
let mergedPath = UIBezierPath()
mergedPath.merge(with: path1)
mergedPath.merge(with: path2)
mergedPath.merge(with: path3)
```

[image]

[image]

```
import UIKit

extension UIBezierPath {
    func merge(with path: UIBezierPath) {
        let currentPath = self.cgPath.mutableCopy()!
        let lastPoint = self.lastPoint()
        let firstPoint = path.firstPoint()
        
        var index = -1
        path.cgPath.applyWithBlock { block in
            index += 1
            let element = block.pointee
            
            switch (element.type) {
            case .moveToPoint:
                if index != 0 && lastPoint != firstPoint || lastPoint == nil {
                    currentPath.move(to: element.points[0])
                }
            case .addLineToPoint:
                currentPath.addLine(to: element.points[0])
            case .addQuadCurveToPoint:
                currentPath.addQuadCurve(to: element.points[1], control: element.points[0])
            case .addCurveToPoint:
                currentPath.addCurve(to: element.points[2], control1: element.points[0], control2: element.points[1])
            case .closeSubpath:
                currentPath.closeSubpath()
            @unknown default:
                fatalError()
            }
        }
        
        self.cgPath = currentPath
    }
    
    func firstPoint() -> CGPoint? {
        var firstPoint: CGPoint? = nil
        
        var index = -1
        self.cgPath.applyWithBlock { block in
            index += 1
            let element = block.pointee
            
            if index == 0 {
                if element.type == .moveToPoint || element.type == .addLineToPoint {
                    firstPoint = element.points[0]
                } else if element.type == .addQuadCurveToPoint {
                    firstPoint = element.points[1]
                } else if element.type == .addCurveToPoint {
                    firstPoint = element.points[2]
                }
            }
        }
        
        return firstPoint
    }
    
    func lastPoint() -> CGPoint? {
        var lastPoint: CGPoint? = nil
        
        var index = -1
        self.reversing().cgPath.applyWithBlock { block in
            index += 1
            let element = block.pointee
            
            if index == 0 {
                if element.type == .moveToPoint || element.type == .addLineToPoint {
                    lastPoint = element.points[0]
                } else if element.type == .addQuadCurveToPoint {
                    lastPoint = element.points[1]
                } else if element.type == .addCurveToPoint {
                    lastPoint = element.points[2]
                }
            }
        }
        
        return lastPoint
    }
}
```

Comment: Vau, very much thank you for this extension! :)

Comment: @sabiland you are welcome. I am glad it helped you

Comment: Is your solution reliable, or should I check it in various scenarios? I do a lot of UIBezierPath operations (randomly generated, etc.).

Comment: I haven't done any exhaustive testing for this method. I am only using this for a specific shape in my app. So please have it tested and let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: Ok. I'll do some thousands random checks. But for now, as I was testing it it works perfectly (no problems).

Comment: I did a 10.000 loop with merging random paths and no problems: https://i.imgur.com/QKlzWPD.png

Comment: @sabiland nice, thank you very much for comprehensive testing and sharing :)