# Merge two UIBezierPath points

Tags: objective-c, ios5, calayer, uibezierpath, quartz-core

I want to be able to select some area from this image, and change the color of the selected area.

[image]

To do this, I thought of using `CALayer` and `UIBezierPath`.

- I've cleared the colored area from the image, then I took each area point and drew a `UIBezierPath` beneath the image.
- I have 3 `CALayer`s for each area, each `CALayer` has a `UIBezierPath` with predefined points.

---

[image]

When the user clicks on a layer, it will show the selected layer without filling the `UIBezierPath`, just to have a border around the `UIBezierPath`, the result look like this:

[image]

- I added a `UIView` over the image with `Opacity = 0.6f` and
  redrew all the `CALayer`s on it.
- All the layers are hidden in the new `UIView`

---

Every thing is working great, the next step is to merge the selected areas:

- I took the points from the first area and added it to the points of
  the second area
- I created a new `UIBezierPath` with the new points

### My problem is that the result is wrong:

[image]

---

1. **How to merge a `UIBezierPath` with a correct points order?**
2. **Is there a better way to accomplish something like this without
   using `UIBezierPath`?**

Comment: Do you want to remove the small gap between the two areas? If not you could just use `- (void)appendPath:(UIBezierPath *)bezierPath` to merge two UIBezierPath.

Comment: i think you should try this [Stackoverflow answare][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942642/merge-connected-uibezierpaths?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

from looking at the image above, the path is wrong because the **sequence** of points is not followed which pretty much screws up your path. I don't think a Bezier Path is the right tool to do this in the first place as you have rectangular or point to point connections. So you more have a Poligon than a Bezier Path object. However UIKit seems to bundle all this into a UIBezierPath object (non optimal naming if you ask me).

The tricky thing here is to find out where the two shapes really touch each other and to add the points in the sequence as before but then tear up the vertical lines in the middle and connect the path to the other structure.

Another alternative could be to use a bitmap and simply union the bitmaps and create a new shape. It largely depends on how your base data is represented and managed. You could also simply keep two shapes and just join them in a meta object to draw them concurrently.